# Consider the 2 parts, does the second one sound a bit redundant?

Tags: meaning

The following 2 parts come from a research paper https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vision-CAIR/MiniGPT-4/main/MiniGPT_4.pdf

> Notably, GPT-4, a large-scale multimodal
> model …
>
> Although GPT-4 has exhibited remarkable capabilities, the methods behind its exceptional abilities are still a mystery. *We believe that these superior skills may stem from the utilization of a more advanced large language model (LLM).*

The first part has already stated that GPT-4 is a large-scale multimodal and the first sentence of the second part spoke of the capabilities of GPT-4. Combining the 2 parts yields that large language models lead to remarkable capabilities or superior skills.

However, the last sentence of the excerpt repeats the meaning and sounds a bit misleading. "A more advanced large language model" seems to be another model that’s more advanced than GPT-4. Actually, GPT-4 is the model from which those superior skills stem.

Is my understanding correct? If yes, how do I improve the last sentence?

Comment: To a first approximation, *a **more advanced** large language model* means *a **larger** large language model* (more training data and/or more or larger "layers" within the neural network). But there are other ways any given system can be made "more advanced" by optimizations that don't involve changing any of those elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight abuse of terminology; namely the first sentence states that GPT4 *is* a large language model, but the second says it *uses* a large language model.

You'd have to be an expert in the technical AI terminology to determine which is technically correct; as per the comment below, GPT-4 is an LLM.  If one is being very strict about the names of things, then OpenAI should choose a different name for the web-based software that allows users to interact with GPT-4.  As, for example, they use a different name for "chatGPT" from the language model "GPT 3.5"

However this may well be a deliberate blurring, and not an error. Experts in the field will be able to interpret the multiple meanings here from context (and non-experts probably don't care about this distinction). Perhaps GPT-4 refers to both a language model, and a web-based text and image (and sound?) processing utility, that uses the language model to respond in a human-like manner to a variety of prompts.

That is, it seems that OpenAI use "GPT4" to refer to both the language model and the artificial intelligence software that uses it.

The last part means that GPT4 (the AI software) uses a more advanced language model (also called GPT4) *than other, previous AI chatbots*, such as chatGPT (which uses GTP-3.5).  That seems to me a relatively obvious assertion, but not an error.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am an expert in AI terminology and I'm pretty sure GPT-4 is a LLM. Anyone can confirm that with ChatGPT or https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll defer to your expertise, and I've edited to reflect this.

Comment: I agree with this answer and this is approximately what I was trying to say in my answer. But I don't think technical AI terminology is all precise and universally agreed. For example Wikipedia says a language model is "a probability distribution over sequences of words," which is obviously not the same as a bot that can answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it repeats anything. It is about a "more advanced" LLM. This means more advanced than other similar AI bots.

Maybe there is a distinction between (a) language models and LLMs in general and (b) AI bots like GPT-4 which include other software components as well.